Run as TestNG not showing in eclipse even after added TestNG from Help>Install new software also added its dependencies in pom.xml
Added TestNG from Help>Install New Software and successfully added TestNG, also added TestNG dependencies into POM.xml. I have created a copy of existing java class, added annotations in class and import the testNG library. When I right click and select 'Run as' it shows 'Run Configurations'. Also when I go to run configurations, testNG not showing there whereas I go to Help>About Eclipse IDE>Installation Details and search for TestNG it is showing me TestNG there..
screenshot of class file:

Screenshot of TestNG installed in eclipse:

I tried installing TestNG also added its dependencies in POM.xml
I am expecting to see Run as TestNG but not able to see that.
